# How to check content of certificate.p12 WITHOUT installing on the Keychain or accessing apple portal

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, ios-provisioning

I have an iOS certificate.p12 file, is it possible to check the content of  .P12 file (iOS certificate + public key) and be sure that it is a correct Distribution certificate and not (development or wildcard), I know it is possible via Apple portal or with installing the certificate on the keychain but is there a way to check the content of this file and be sure that it is a distribution Certificate with out apple portal check and without installing the file?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

what I want is to check the customers distribution certificate.p12,
instead of installing their certificate in my keychain each time, I want to have a mechanism to check the content of certificate and let me know that this certificate is not expired and also it is distribution certificate, I want to know if it is possible or not?

> 1.Expiration Date
>
> 2. It it is Distribution or not

Comment: You are aware the question says you want to do this IN iOS?

Comment: @GaryRiches sorry was my mistake, thanks for correction

Comment: Do you have a copy of your distribution certificate available for comparison?

Comment: @IanMacDonald well, I have a distribution certificate, but what I want is to check the customer distribution certificate

Answer (score 25):

to check the expiration date :
first extract .p12 to .pem :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -out certificate.pem -nodes
```

then get the expiration date :

```
cat certificate.pem | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
```

Comment: Why not omit `-out certificate.pem` and pipe the result of the first command directly into the `openssl x509` of the second?